# Is there a function in MATLAB similar to $\tt freqz$ but for $H(\omega)$?

Tags: matlab, frequency

I wanted to know if there's a MATLAB function that equates the frequency response, $H(\omega)$ of a system. Something similar to `freqz` like a `freqw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For continuous-time systems and the s-plane where a point $i\omega$ (or $j\omega$ in electronics engineering notation) on the imaginary axis corresponds to frequency $\omega$, there is `freqs`, see [MATLAB documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqs.html).